# How to upload file to firebase storage from nodejs - client side

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, command-line-interface, firebase-storage

I want to write a CLI app in nodejs that authenticates and uploads a file to firebase, I installed the `firebase` npm package but it is not well suited for NodeJS (client-side) use.

How can I authenticate and upload a file to firebase storage?

Comment: Does this help? See the examples in this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: that's for a browser env, I'm running a nodejs CLI

Answer (score 1):

There are two Node.js modules for Firebase, one for server-side Node.js code, and another one for client-side Node.js code (like on IoT devices).

If you're running the code on a server, you'll want to [use the Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start). Note that this part of the Admin SDK is a fairly thin wrapper around the regular [Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage), so I also recommend keeping the documentation for that package handy.

If you're running the code on a client, unfortunately the Node.js module does not have built-in support for uploading files to Storage. You'll have to look for another way, such as creating a custom API that your code calls and that uses a supported SDK for uploading the file to Storage.